# Dynamically inject js/css files in ui-router from file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `ŧest.json` file:

```
{
  "general": 
          {
            "css": [
              "css/test.css"
            ],
            "js": [
              "js/test.js"
            ]
          }
}
```

and the following code for my angularjs app:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('home', {
              url: '/',
              templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
              resolve: {
                loadAssets: ['DynamicService', function (DynamicService) {
                    return DynamicService.get();
                  }]
              }
            })
```

and here is my service to get file content as js object:

```
.factory('DynamicService', ['$resource', '$q', '$http',
      function ($resource, $q, $http) {

        var dynService = {};
        var dynUrl = 'api/dynService'; // API to get "ŧest.json" file content

        var error = function (response) {
          // ...
        };

        dynService.get = function () {
          return $http
                  .get(dynUrl)
                  .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                  }, error);
        };

        return dynService;

      }]);
```

I would like to dynamically load those files `css/test.css` and `js/test.js` files, taken after reading the `ŧest.json` file, before completing router initialization, so that, when visiting `/`, those files will be injected to DOM.

As you can see, I tried that code in `$stateProvider` but it does not work.

Any help please?
I have angularjs `v1.7.0`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are on the right direction, Ui-Router `resolve` property when gets Promise, it will wait till it resolves and only then will transition to the state ('/').

All you need to do, is to return a promise that waits till all `css` & `js` files are loaded.
You can achieve that using [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) that receives array of promises and return a new promise that will resolve whenever all of them will resolve.

Small example:

```js
factory('DynamicService', ['$resource', '$q', '$http',
  function($resource, $q, $http) {

    var dynService = {};
    var dynUrl = 'api/dynService'; // API to get "ŧest.json" file content

    var error = function(response) {
      // ...
    };

    var loadAsset = function(url, type) {
      var defered = $q.defer();
      if (type === 'js') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.onload = defered.resolve;
        script.onerror = defered.reject;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } else if (type === 'css') {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.href = url;
        link.onload = defered.resolve;
        link.onerror = defered.reject;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
      }
      return defered.promise;
    }

    var loadAssets = function(assets) {
      // prepare a list of promises & return promise that waits to all.
      var allPromises = ['css', 'js'].reduce((acc, key) => {
        var currentAssets = assets.general[key].map((url) => loadAsset(url, key));
        return acc.concat(currentAssets);
      }, []);

      return $q.all(allPromises);
    }

    dynService.get = function() {
      return $http
        .get(dynUrl)
        .then(function(response) {
          return loadAssets(response.data);
        }, error);
    };

    return dynService;

  }
]);
```